# Stop services, run batch files, then start services

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I've to stop multiples services, check the services if they are correctly stopped THEN run multiple batch files. When the batch jobs are done, start again the stopped services at the first place. I started the following script but could not go further.

```
#Define Services
$service1 = 'StiSvc'
$service2 = 'AdobeARMservice'
$services = @(
  $service1,
  $service2
)

#Stop Services
Get-Service | 
  Where { $services -contains $_.Name } |
  Foreach {
    $_ | Stop-Service
  }

#Verify Services
Get-Service | 
  Where { $services -contains $_.Name } |
  Foreach {
    if ((Get-Service $_.Name).Status -eq "stopped") {
      Write-Host 'Service Stop Pass (0)'
    } else {
      Write-Host 'Service Stop Failed (1000)';
      exit '1000'
    }
  }

#Start batch
if ($services.Status -eq "Stopped") {
  Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c C:\download\hello.bat"
} else {
  Start-Sleep -s 10
}
```

Comment: And what's the actual question?

Comment: So, what is your question? What doesn't work as expected? You "could not go further" ... *how?*

Comment: It’s not working as expected. The services stop but the batch file is not starting.

Comment: Try using the call operator for running the batch file(s): `& "C:\download\hello.bat"` (just like that, without `Start-Process` or `cmd /c`)

Comment: I tried this but no joy so far.

Comment: Define "no joy". How did you verify that the script didn't run? What's the content of the script?

Comment: Because it's highly unlikely that the two services you've used are really the ones you're stopping _(as they really wouldn't prevent the running of your batch files)_. I would suggest that you provide the real service names and the console outputs. (for that you may even be better off ensuring that $_.Name is output along side each pass or fail message).

Comment: Have you tried doing this all manually from the cmd prompt or powershell .  Run the commands one at a time from the powershell prompt to stop each service or use the `NET` command from the cmd prompt to stop the services. Then try to run your batch files. You have to learn to debug your programs.

Comment: `if ($services.Status -eq "Stopped") `  `$services` is an array of strings, is does not have a `.Status` property and is never `Stopped` You could add variable `[bool]$AllStopped` and check for that.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
$services = 'StiSvc', 'AdobeARMservice'

Stop-Service $services -ErrorAction Stop

& 'C:\download\hello.bat'
& 'C:\path\to\other.cmd'
#...

Start-Service $services
```

If it doesn't, you need to provide more information about what exactly fails, and how. Include all error and status messages.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,
I modified the script as follow. The script stops 2 services, when the 2 services are stopped it start the batch file.

```
#Stop Services

Get-Service StiSvc, AdobeARMservice | Stop-Service

#Verify Services

if (((Get-Service StiSvc).Status -eq "stopped") -and 
((Get-Service AdobeARMservice).Status -eq "stopped"))

# Start batch

{Start-Process  "cmd.exe"  "/c C:\download\hello.bat"}
```

I’m working on to improve the script. I’ll come back to you asap.
Regards